# How to implement a Nadex autotrading bot?

Tags: python, api, trading, algorithmic-trading

I have been searching for a way to autotrade on Nadex

> https://www.nadex.com

and came across this script https://github.com/FreeTheQuarks/NadexBot

It is an old script and I am not that experienced in Python.

**`Q1:`** Is this a good way to go about, thus since it is not a official API and is probably scraping data from the site, which would mean slower requests and trade execution?

---

There is also an unofficial API client https://github.com/knoguchi/nadex/tree/master/nadex

But again, not sure if good for live trading.

**`Q2:`** Is there better ways to go about this and if so where should I start?

Comment: the posted links are dead
this might be the same project though am not sure. I joined the dots from the answers given
https://github.com/ak9250/NadexBot

Comment: @Lucem The link you provided is dead now too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of the Nadex unofficial API Python client.
I still maintain it. Recently the streamer support was added.
However, I suggest that you use [JavaScript from nadex.com](https://trade.nadex.com/fe/common/script/IG.js?v=6.0.6). It's always up-to-date and works just like the official web site, obviously.

The JS code is professionally written.  Very readable.  There are 100 JavaScript files but essential ones for the API access are only handful.

Nadex is a part of IG Group. Hence the JS has lots of IG namespace. [IG offers API and documents](https://labs.ig.com/) for developers.  Nadex message format is a little different from IG's but the design is same.  Once you learn the document, all the JavaScript code is really easy to understand.

Comment: A nice move, Kenji. Would you mind updating the README.md? It states almost for all but two functions **No** ( as not implemented, which seems to have been a bit changed forwards, as you posted here ). Also might want to remove a typo in a column header ( *(cit.:)* "Opeartion" - just move the "r" one pos. left ). **Stay tuned & enjoy this great Community.**

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I will update the doc.  I think I can write the [NadexBot](https://github.com/FreeTheQuarks/NadexBot) using my client library.  That'd be a good test case.

Comment: I have browsed roughly the scope of services, but you ought be best informed to ask about --- Does the NADEX-provided streaming service contain also Depth-Of-Market records for the traded instruments in real-time? Does it include the whole LP-DoM or just the book records about the NADEX-inhouse-positions? Thanks for your kind response and insight, Kenji.

Comment: The official web trader shows [up to 5 level of DoM](https://www.nadex.com/sites/default/files/images/platform-screenshots/trader-platform-depth-of-market.png) in the ticket screen.  I don't know if it's whole or inhouse.  If you search for `IG.ticketFidsNG` in the JS there are `AS1..AS5` and `BD1..BD5`.  They are the streaming subscription keys.  I've never tested other than AS1 and BD1 but I'm pretty sure the rest of the keys give you the 5 level DoM.

Comment: Kenji your API works great.  However I couldn't figure out how to get underlying index quotes like current level of USDJPY.  Can you add that or say how to do its

Answer (score 1):

### **`A1:`** Measure Twice Rather Before One Cut$

Simply put, it is your money you trade with, so warnings like this one ( from FreeTheQuarks )

> *(cit.:*)
> **This was the first non-trivial program I wrote.
> It hasn't received any significant updates in years.
> I've only made minor readability updates after first putting this on git.**

should give one a sufficient sign to re-think the risks, before one puts a first dollar on table.

This is a for-profit game, isn't it?

---

### **`A2:`** Yes, there is a better way.

All quantitatively supported trading strategies need stable and consistent care - i.e. one needs to have

1. rock-solid historical data
2. stable API to work with ( Trade Execution & Management, Market Events )
3. reliable & performant testbed for validating one's own quantitative model of the trading strategy

Having shared this piece of some 100+ man*years experience, one may decide on one's own whether to rely on or rather forget to start any reasonable work with just some reverse-engineering efforts on an "un-official API client".

In case the profit generation capability of some trading strategy supports the case, one may safely order an outsourced technical implementation and technical integration efforts in a turn-key manner.

> **`Epilogue:`**
> If there are quantitatively supported reasons to implement a trading strategy,
> the profit envelope thereof sets the ultimate economically viable model
> for having that strategy automated and operated in-vivo.
> **Failure to decide in this order of precedence
> results in nothing but wasted time & money.
> *Your money.***

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the Nadex platform recently too. I wrote a small wrapper over the oanda foreign exchange broker api v1 in python (now they have v2.0) so I have some experience.

To implement an autotrading bot is a big question, but to try and answer: you may either use a pre-existing wrapper for the Nadex API (it looks like either Python or Javascript are your choices), or write one yourself, in a language of your preference.

1. If you want to start from scratch, I believe Nadex offers a RESTful service, which basically means you can make GET, POST, DELETE, and other types of requests via a specific URL (most of the time there is a 'base' URL from where other endpoints spawn). I would first go about trying to find the endpoints to the Nadex servers - Kenjis unofficial API should point in the right direction there, since he is using URL strings and has a class for making different requests. I was unsuccessful trying to find any documentation for Nadex API myself, but Kenji's wrapper or the Javascript API both look promising. Depending on the depth of the market and number of requests, I think you are correct saying that you wouldn't want a web scraper for something like this. It would be very slow (and probably wasteful of time) compared to using an existing wrapper. I would start writing classes and/or functions that make simple requests to the Nadex RESTFUL endpoints, for example a function that logs in the accesses account data. Next step would be to retrieve market data and eventually stream the market data into a trade logic algorithm that makes decisions for you.
2. If you want to build a trading bot easily and with most of the work cut out for you, I would recommend one of the other answers here. That way, you can use their predefined classes/functions and have the "boring" API access code written for you, ready to use.

Hope that helps or leads you in the right direction!